# How to take input in one line and separately store them in different variables

Tags: c#

So i want to ask that suppose if i am taking input like 2+5 in one line so i want to separate them in 3 different variables like int a=2, b=3 and char operator = '+'

P.S: just trying to tweak my simple calculator program

Comment: You can use split method.

Comment: that approach is error prone, rather I would suggest asking each part separately that way you can validate input easily, if you like my idea i will post an answer about it.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw sure

Comment: @DanialAhmed i will provide you a solution with what i think is easy and simple way to do it

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw yeah please share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `split` method

> Splits a string into substrings that are based on the characters in an array.

**SYNTAX:**

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

[See more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Split will remove +?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to get each component more reliably (i.e., this supports int numbers of any length):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "20+5";

        var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)(.)(\d+)");

        if (regex.IsMatch(input))
        {
            var match = regex.Match(input);
            var a = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var op = match.Groups[2].Value;
            var b = match.Groups[3].Value;

            Console.WriteLine($"a: {a}");
            Console.WriteLine($"operator: {op}");
            Console.WriteLine($"b: {b}");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
a: 20
operator: +
b: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string strResult = Console.ReadLine();

 //On here, we are splitting your result if user type one line both numbers with "+" symbol. After splitting, 
// we are converting them to integer then storing the result to array of integer.
 int[] intArray = strResult.Split('+').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Now you can now access your numbers via its index

```
 intArray[0] 
 //or 
 intArray[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> So i want to ask that suppose if i am taking input like 2+5 in one
>   line so i want to separate them in 3 different variables like int a=2,
>   b=3 and char operator = '+'

you can use params array to pass any number of parameters to a method and then you can just split them.

**Example:**

```
public int Result(params char[] input){
  // split the input 
  // any necessary parsing/converting etc.
  // do some calculation
 // return the value
}
```

Comment: This does not even address the OP's original problem, which is how to parse the input. This explicitly takes three different inputs.

Comment: if you read our chat within his question, he clearly stated that he was happy if i provided an alternative solution.......

Comment: Then the question should have been edited as well. The page should stand on its own.